# How to access bitcoin server's RPC interface remotely?

Tags: bitcoind, json-rpc

I am running a bitcoin daemon (launched via plist file) on MacOS with these parameters:

- `-server` (to accept command line and JSON-RPC commands)
- `-daemon` (to run in the background as a daemon and accept commands)
- `-txindex=1` (I need to maintain a full transaction index for testing purposes)

Both my bitcoin.conf and settings.json files are empty, and I want to use the random cookie authentication.

The node is running fine, has a local address 192.168.83.33, generates a .cookie file,  and is actually connected to 10 peers on tcp4 port 8333.

I would like to test the JSON-RPC API via HTTP (from another computer in the same local net) with the example command described in the [bitcoin wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/API_reference_(JSON-RPC)):

```
curl --data-binary '{"jsonrpc": "1.0", "id":"curltest", "method": "getblockchaininfo", "params": [] }' -H 'content-type: text/plain;' http://192.168.83.33:8333/
```

But I am receiving just empty replies (`curl: (52) Empty reply from server`), even when I try from the same node (on localhost address 127.0.0.1:8333)

Since I want to rely on random cookie authentication, I did not set any rpcuser. Do I need to pass the cookie file in the HTTP header (via curl's --cookie parameter)?

Bonus question: How can I set up one or more peer I would like to connect (along or instead of the random select pool)?

Comment: You need to pass the cookie's contents as HTTP auth username/password (username `__cookie__`, password a long hex string) if you manually connect. `bitcoin-cli` will do this automatically for you.

Comment: @PieterWuille I tried it already (with curl -u), and the client is working. What else could I check?

Comment: So did that fix the problem? What else is there to check?

Comment: @PieterWuille no. I mean the bitcoin-cli client is working, but I would like to test JSON-RPC commands via HTTP/curl, and write some JSON-RPC tool to play around with.

Comment: Are you sending the username and password from the cookie file?